# What does "Ignore" and "Ignore All" really mean in Spell Check

Tags: usability, user-expectation, best-practice, spell-checking

Let's look at the below statement:[image]

What happens when you ignore the word "beleeve" from the sentence.

1. It ignores it for the current session. If a new session is created
   it shows it as an error.
2. It ignores that specific word from that specific document. But will
   show it as an error if the word is written again on the document.
3. Does the document continue to ignore the word even if we close and re-open it?

There seems to be no consensus / pattern in using Ignore or Ignore all. please check the screenshots below match the patterns. It is quite inconsistent throughout the industry.

How could one understand the best experience for the user?

Few examples of the most commonly used editors ( Online and software ):

1 - **Google Drive** 
[image]

2 - **Word**
[image]

3 - **Zoho Docs** 
[image]

4 - **Pages**
[image]

5 - **Evernote** 
[image]

Comment: And "add to dictionary" lets you add it permanently to the dictionary so that it is always ignored. (I have mostly used that for names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ignore** means that the word will be ignored that time.

**Ignore All** means that it will ignore all occurrences of that word in that document

This is a really common pattern, Word uses both of them, [Google docs also uses it](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/57859?hl=en):

> If you want to ignore the spell-check tool’s suggestions for a given
>   word, click the Ignore button to move on to the next word. If you want
>   the tool to ignore that word wherever it appears in your document,
>   click the drop-down arrow next to the "Ignore" button and select
>   Ignore all.

and Word capture:

[image]

and same for all software I tried

in short: not only there's consensus, but this is an extremely common pattern, therefore **the answer would be your second option**

> It ignores that specific word from that specific document. But will
>   show it as an error if the word is written again on the document.

Comment: I apologize, maybe I did not frame my question correctly. What I meant by no consensus is that some tools use " Ignore" while some use "Ignore all " while some use both. And that there was no specific pattern on what is considered good practice.